# Android Navigation Drawer : whether to use Relative Layout or Drawer Layout as parent?

Tags: android, material-design, navigation-drawer

I am working on an application, in which I need to implement navigation drawer in my MainActivity. I have a question whether I should make "android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout" as parent or the "Relative Layout" which I am using for the MainActivity as parent Element and why ?

Comment: If all the `View`s in your `Activity` are going to be within the `DrawerLayout`, then just use that as the parent. If you want `View`s to appear outside of the `DrawerLayout` - e.g., you want a `Toolbar` to be above the drawer and main content - then use another `ViewGroup` as the parent, with the `DrawerLayout` inside.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Now I understand It clearly